# All Faces to Individual Objects

Tags: mesh, objects, faces

I am looking for a way to take all the faces of an object and make each face it's own object.
[image: Basic object to desired solution, each face it's own object.]

In the image above, you'll see a basic representation of what I'm trying to accomplish. On the left is a shape with faces, all attached. On the right is the result I want, an object for each face. The project I'm working on is much more complicated than this example, so I can't select each face and separate by selection. I have over 3,000 faces to work on.

Comment: A thumbs up for writing good image alt text.

Comment: @David Thanks! Haha. I know it's important for screen readers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In edit mode with all the faces selected, press <kbd>space</kbd> type `split` and select *Edge Split*. Then press <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts*. Every face is now a separate object.

*Warning* separating 3000 faces into different objects will take a while, if not crash blender.
After splitting the faces, you may have to brake up your mesh in to smaller pieces, then run the *By Loose Parts* command. You can select (say half of the faces) and separate them into different objects with <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*.

If you need the new objects' origins relocated, you can select all the objects and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*. Or if that keyboard short cut is too long, in the 3D view header *Object > Transform > Origin to Geometry*.

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks, @David!

Comment: @JeffLange edited my answer to include setting the objects' origin.

Answer (score 6):

also you can copy, paste and run this code, making all with 1 clic :D  :

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split()
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

[image: script]

---

**UPDATE**

in order to set the "origin_geometry" in each new face run this:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split()
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
```

[image: script2]

Comment: could you modify it to also set the origin point to geometry? I didn't mention that in the text, but it's also a step in my workflow.

Comment: @JeffLange ready.. only was 1 line

Answer (score 1):

Another option - use and apply the Edge split modifier (play with angle setting to tell it above what angle it would split edges)

Comment: This wouldn't split the objects up, though. Thanks anyways.