# Partitioning/ segmenting a 2D plane

Tags: mesh, objects

How can I uniformly divide a plane into even segments?
I am hoping to split a 2D rectangular plane into a series of smaller rectangles along its long horizontal axis before animating each individual piece differently.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23821/how-can-i-subdivide-this-plane-into-even-squares

Comment: Related: [All Faces to Individual Objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24173/2217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With your 2D plane selected, enter edit mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
- Move your mouse along one of the long edges.
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
- Roll your mouse wheel until you see the correct number of cuts (in purple).
- Click the left mouse button.
- Click the right mouse button.

Your plane will now be subdivided into equal parts.

You can now separate them into individual objects by selecting each one in turn (in face select mode) then hitting <kbd>P</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: Ah! beat me to it by seconds... D:

Comment: Or if you are looking to split into 100s or 1000s.. start with one section, add an array modifier for how many sections you want, apply the modifier, then edit hit P , choose separate by parts.