# How to "Separate by loose parts" in 2.90?

Tags: mesh, objects, interface, shortcut, navigation

I use the search function for everything in blender when I can. That could be a bad habit though, because now "Separate by loose parts" doesn't come up in search (2.90) and I do not know how to do it optimally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All Faces to Individual Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24173/all-faces-to-individual-objects)

Comment: You just have to search for "separate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to Hit <kbd>P</kbd> on the keyboard and select one of the options.

Comment: Same as with previous versions indeed.